# Do dogs 'sigh out of contentment'?

Tags: dogs, behavior, health, psychology, vocalizations

Over the years, I have noticed with all of my dogs that after I have given some sweet talk and ear scratches, they will give out a long sigh.

I am hoping this is out of contentment. Is there any basis in fact to support that?

Comment: If you have some ideas about new tags, please feel welcome to start a new Pets Meta Q&A about this or create the tag yourself (I am sorry but I do not know how does creating new tags work, so I cannot help in this). A lot of existing tags seem obsolete or sub-optimal and I support the idea of creating new ones.

Comment: In my experience, when a user has attained a certain rep, they may suggest a tag. After that , it goes through a review process on the review queue. I do a lot of this on EL&U.

Comment: A former cat used to sigh nightly after getting tucked in bed with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s research on dogs vocalizing and humans understanding. Many studies focus on barking; but it seems reasonable that interspecies communication would also be possible with other vocalizations (e.g. sighs).

> Dogs use a wide range of different context-specific subunits of barks and mixed sounds as a means for communication of emotional arousal and both positive and negative emotional states.

> In addition, humans seem to be able to correctly identify the emotional state of the dog based on context-specific barks.

Citation: Csoltova E and Mehinagic E (2020) *[Where Do We Stand in the Domestic Dog (Canis familiaris) Positive-Emotion Assessment: A State-of-the-Art Review and Future Directions.](https://internal-journal.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2020.02131/full)* Front. Psychol. 11:2131. doi: 10.3389/fpsyg.2020.02131

Comment: Yes, the fact that many humans can interpret these vocalizations would seem to suggest inter-species understanding.